# WPF different foreground color for a particular text datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, foreground

Iam getting used to WPF slowly. Now, Iam thinking whether this thing is possible in WPF or not. What I want is I want to color only particular words inside a datagrid row.
For Eg : If text is "WPF is just amazingly beautiful", I just want to change foreground of "amazingly" rest other remains the same. And 1 more thing , Iam populating Datagrid programatically. So how can I do this task in program?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out templatecolumn with richtextbox

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. But can i change color of a particular text in the richtextbox programatically?

Comment: Yes that should be possible